# what difference between proto=WPA and proto=RSN in wpa_supplicant.conf

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I have read the official doc here: https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

My question is what difference between two example below?

one conf is:

```
    network={
        ssid="example"
        proto=WPA
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        psk=xxxxxxxxx
    }
```

another is:

```
    network={
        ssid="example"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        psk=xxxxxxxxx
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but I was looking for the same thing you were. The doc you linked to in your question (https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) appears to explain it, at least to the extent I wanted to understand. Just incase you missed it I'll quote the relevant part here.

```
# proto: list of accepted protocols
# WPA = WPA/IEEE 802.11i/D3.0
# RSN = WPA2/IEEE 802.11i (also WPA2 can be used as an alias for RSN)
# Note that RSN is used also for WPA3.
# If not set, this defaults to: WPA RSN
```

So WPA is for original WPA and RSN is for WPA2 (but you can type in WPA2 instead if you want), RSN also works for WPA3 it says.